Is there any alternative other than Graph API to take Facebook's datas in .net?
After my research it is very hard to pass this(I mention below) step to use Graph API.

Business verification This is required to get access to data from
users (for some apps this is called advanced access). Only people with
full control of a Business Account can complete this process. Learn
more about business verification.

Is there any way or package to get data from facebook in .net platform?

Using the API is not dependent on what package you use. The only alternative would be scraping - but that is explicitly against Facebook's ToS.
